# Where should I unregister UWP Application.Current.Suspending event?

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to perform a set of operation when my application is suspended. I've registered my event as described in [Handle app suspending](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/suspend-an-app) calling registration in page constructor.

```
 public MainPage()
 {
     Application.Current.Suspending += MainPage_Suspending;

     ...
 }
```

However I haven't found any reference on how properly unregister this event. Having registered suspending event inside Page constructor unregister it inside the `Unload` event of page doesn't seem right.

Where should I unregister my suspending event? Should I move registering inside `Loaded` event and unregister inside `Unloaded` event instead of using constructor?

Comment: It depends on your scenario. The event is app-wide and thus I'm not sure if using it in page constructor is a good choice, though this also depends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to listen to events on static classes in your page instance it is best practice to subscribe in the Page.Loaded event and unsubscribe in the Page.Unloaded event.

Thanks!

Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform